# Какой частью речи является слово "холодно"?

Tags: грамматика

Какой частью речи является слово "холодно" в предложении "Сегодня холодно"? Это категория состояния, или нет? Как правильно ответить на экзамене?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.

Мне попалась книга А.М. Чепасова «Современный русский язык. Таблицы по грамматике», изд.1999 г. Первая тема называется «Типы классификации частей речи». Рассмотрены 4 таблицы (Виноградова, Гвоздева, 1953 года, 1980 года). В первых трех таблицах категория состояния присутствует, а в четвертой ее нет. В Грамматике-80, действительно, такого понятия нет, да и безличных предложений, кажется,  тоже нет. Предложение «Сегодня холодно» относится к однокомпонентным предложениям с предикативным наречием. Тогда я взяла книжку поновее – К. Рахимкулова «Морфология современного русского языка». Там дается информация о двух школах, по-разному определяющих категорию состояния.

Вот я и хотела узнать, по «какой школе» учат в нашей средней школе. И вообще неоднозначность ситуации напрягает: в Грамматике-80 даются неплохие разборы предложений, а можно ли на них ориентироваться в школьной практике?

Примечание. Я никому ничего не ставлю, потому что еще не разобралась, как это надо делать. Для комментариев  мне нужно 10 знаков, про плюсы-минусы я вообще не знаю. О принятии самих вопросов часто трудно судить: я спрашиваю, чтобы что-то понять или в чем-то убедиться,  и обычно несколько человек помогают мне в этом.  Тем не менее, постараюсь просмотреть свои вопросы и принять те, где это можно сделать.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2. Я пользуюсь книгой "Русская грамматика/Белоусов В. и др.; под ред. Шведовой и Лопатина, 1990 год. Она опирается на двухтомную академическую "Русскую грамматику" 1980 года тех же авторов. Можно ли ее считать "лопатинской" грамматикой? Непонятно вот что: зачем надо было отменять слова категории состояния и безличные предложения, увеличивая разрыв между школьным и вузовским образованием. Или это шаг вперед, а школа потом подтянется?

Comment: Можно вопрос? Почему Вы никому не ставите ни плюсы, ни минусы?

Comment: "Плюс"- это палец, поднятый вверх. "Минус" - вниз. "Грамматика-80", точнее, ее синтаксис, никакого отношения к школьной грамматике не имеют. Скорее, "Грамматика-70". Но ее в Сети найти не могу. Я поступила в университет в 1980 году, как раз в год выхода новой Грамматики. Был у нас и профессор, принимавший участие в создании этой Грамматики. Так вот на тот момент отношение к ней было очень неоднозначным. Учили нас все-таки по Грамматике -70, она более классическая.

Comment: А с этой Грамматикой знакомили, показывая, что есть и другие позиции, с которых можно посмотреть. Там, действительно, мы не найдем многих привычных терминов синтаксиса. А Вы когда учились? (Если не секрет?)

Comment: София, Вы пользуетесь слабым телефонным браузером, который не отображает всех опций, скорее всего.

Answer (score 8):

Да, это категория состояния, отличается от наречия синтаксической функцией: является главным членом безличного предложения. Да и Вы сами это знаете. Конечно, неоднозначная часть речи. Какой момент хотите  обсудить?

Comment: Ответ на дополнение 2. Ученые вообще работают без оглядки на школу. В школе теория, если можно так сказать, классическая, без новаций.

Comment: @Ларf! Объясните, пожалуйста: как всё-таки правильно: 1) Да Вы и сами это знаете (из Вашего ответа)  - или 2) Да Вы и сама (сам) это знаете? (я уже настолько давно говорю так, что мне казалось, что я говорю правильно: привык к этому)

Comment: Есть и третий вариант: "Да Вы и сама (сам) это знаешь". Смайл — на выбор.

Comment: Замечательный ответ!!! Спасибо. Крыть нечем.

Comment: А что, у меня неправильно? И сама только так говорю, и все вокруг. Даже не могу представить, что можно по-другому. Но нужно посмотреть, может и по-Вашему тоже допустимо.

Answer (score 0):

Когда я учился в институте,педагог говорила,что << сейчас  такие слова относятся к категории состояния( 2001-2006года)Но вот что я нашел на Академике.http://dic.academic.ru/contents.nsf/lingvistic/